# Laravel eager loading unnecessary query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

So lets imagine that we have 2 model 'A' and 'B'.
Model 'A' has two belongsTo relations to 'B' model by different foreignKey.
For example in database we have 2 records with structure

```
 id | first_id | second_id
 1        1          2
 2        2          1
```

So the problem is when i do that:

```
 A::with(['first', 'second'])->get()
```

It calls two same sql query for retrive relation

```
select * from `B` where `B`.`id` in (1, 2) and `B`.`deleted_at` is null
select * from `B` where `B`.`id` in (1, 2) and `B`.`deleted_at` is null
```

So how to avoid that?

P.S Model class

```
class A extends Model {
    public function first() {
        return $this->belongsTo(B::class, 'first_id');
    }

    public function second() {
        return $this->belongsTo(B::class, 'second_id');
    }
}
```

b model is empty

Comment: are you positively sure you aren't calling something twice?

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai yes

Comment: How are your relations setup (your model files)? What is the use case of having table A belonging to table B twice? (out of interest)

Comment: @Chris model A has two belongsTo model B has 2 hasOne idk what exactly you want

Comment: Add your model code to the question

Comment: @nullifier include your model relationships set-up.

Comment: @Chris added...

Comment: This is the expected behavior. In this particular case, you could optimize the executed queries. But it's a rather rare case and would require *a lot* of work.